# Getting background to be same width as text, but different height

Tags: css, background-color

I am trying to get a certain look in pure css (no images).

What I have is:

```
<h2>
    <a>TITLE</a>
</h2>
```

I would like for the text "title" to have a black background that is the same width as the text, but a different height.

I have tried this is various permutations: (ie. span in the link, span in the h2, h2 display inline and the span a block)

```
<h2 class="title section-title">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/artwork/illustrations" >
        Illustrations<span class="title-bg"></span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

If I get the width right, I can't change the height because the span is an inline element. If I get the height right by making the span a block, I can't change get the width to be exactly the width of the text because it is now a block level element and expands to be the entire width of the page.

Any ideas, or will I simply have to use an image?

Comment: for those who wonder how to set a blockquote width (that would need to fit on the left of a picture) use *display: block; overflow: hidden;*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `position: relative;` to the `<a>`, and `position: absolute;` to the `.title-bg` `<span>`. Then set the `top` as appropriate, the `left` to `0`, and the `width` and `height` as appropriate.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/3uzbV/

Answer (score 14):

Use `display:inline-block;`.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awKmj/1/).

```css
h2 {
    display:inline-block;
    height:60px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<h2><a>Hello.</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach I use is `line-height`.

```css
h2 a {color:#fff; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; background:#333;}​
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/teFdZ/).

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```css
a {
    font-size:1em;
    padding:1em 0 1em 0;/*set top and bottom padding to make up extra height*/
    background-color:#063;
}
```

Try this. Even inline elements can have padding.